# Chrome proxy API not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, proxy, http-proxy

I want to set my Chrome proxy using an extension. This is my background.js file:

```
var config = {
    mode: "fixed_servers",
    rules: {
        proxyForHttp: {
            scheme: "http",
            host: "My IP",
            port: // My port as INT
        }
    }
};

chrome.proxy.settings.set(
{
    value: config,
    scope: "regular"
}, function() {});
```

It doesn't change my IP, what am I doing wrong?

And also, how can I set the proxy for just one website and how can I turn it off?

Comment: Does `chrome://net-internals/#proxy` show anything?

Comment: Check the background page console for errors.

Comment: @wOxxOm No errors.

Comment: @JoshLee It shows: "Proxy server for HTTP: *my proxy IP*". So it should work, but when I check my IP, it's still mine.